# Regex pattern for requirements

Tags: python-3.x

I'm finding a solutions for these requirements:

- The username must at least 6 characters long and not exceed 16 characters
- The username must contain only letters, number and optionally a hyphen (-)
- The username must start with a letter, and must not end with a hyphen (-)

What I've tried so far:

```
re.match(r'[\w-]+$', user_name)
```

but is not matching with requirements. Any idea?  I'm pretty new to python.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you have given will match any number of alphanumeric characters or hyphens, so you have met the second requirement partially but not the other two. To keep things simple, it is easiest to implement these three requirements as three separate regexes.

For the first requirement, making sure something is between 6 and 16 characters long can be done with a [greedy quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html), which checks that a pattern repeats between two numbers of times:

```
^.{6, 16}$
```

For the second requirement, we need to check the contents of the input are alphanumeric and that only one hyphen is present. We can check this is the case by matching one hyphen and specifying that all other characters in the string either side of the hyphen must be alphanumeric:

```
^\w*-\w*$
```

For the third requirement, we just check the first character is alphanumeric, the last character is NOT a hyphen and allow anything to match in-between those two:

```
^\w.*[^-]$
```

Applying those three regexes sequentially will enable you to validate the username in the way you want, and an added bonus is that if one of the validation checks does fail, you can feed back to the user what specifically was wrong with their input, since you've split the three requirements into three separate regex checks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z][\w|\-]{6,16}[\w]$
```

From your requirements (sorted for simplicity):

1. The username must contain only letters, number and optionally a hyphen (-)

> **[\w|-]**: Matches any word character or hyphen

2. The username must at least 6 characters long and not exceed 16 characters

> **{6,16}**: Matches between 6 and 16 times the giving back as needed

3. The username must start with a letter, and must not end with a hyphen (-)

> **^[a-zA-Z]**: Matches the first char at the begin of the string
>
> **[\w]$**: The string must ends width a char or number

Answer (score 0):

You can try, assuming the line of text only contains the username :

```
re.match(r'^[A-z][A-z0-9\-]{4,14}[A-z0-9]$')
```

Note that \w match letters, characters, and also _ (underscore)
try it : https://regex101.com/r/V7Mrzk/2